# PyTorch RNN is more efficient with `batch_first=False`?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

In machine translation, we always need to slice out the first timestep (the SOS token) in the annotation and prediction.

When using `batch_first=False`, slicing out the first timestep still keeps the tensor contiguous.

```py
import torch
batch_size = 128
seq_len = 12
embedding = 50

# Making a dummy output that is `batch_first=False`
batch_not_first = torch.randn((seq_len,batch_size,embedding))
batch_not_first = batch_first[1:].view(-1, embedding) # slicing out the first time step
```

However, if we use `batch_first=True`, after slicing, the tensor is no longer contiguous. We need to make it contiguous before we can do different operations such as `view`.

```py
batch_first = torch.randn((batch_size,seq_len,embedding))
batch_first[:,1:].view(-1, embedding) # slicing out the first time step

output>>>
"""
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a9bd590a1679> in <module>
----> 1 batch_first[:,1:].view(-1, embedding) # slicing out the first time step

RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
"""
```

Does that mean `batch_first=False` is better, at least, in the context of machine translation? Since it saves us from doing the `contiguous()` step. Is there any cases that `batch_first=True` works better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Performance

There doesn't seem to be a considerable difference between `batch_first=True` and `batch_first=False`. Please see the script below:

```
import time

import torch


def time_measure(batch_first: bool):
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    layer = torch.nn.RNN(10, 20, batch_first=batch_first).cuda()
    if batch_first:
        inputs = torch.randn(100000, 7, 10).cuda()
    else:
        inputs = torch.randn(7, 100000, 10).cuda()


    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    start = time.perf_counter()

    for chunk in torch.chunk(inputs, 100000 // 64, dim=0 if batch_first else 1):
        _, last = layer(chunk)

    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    return time.perf_counter() - start


print(f"Time taken for batch_first=False: {time_measure(False)}")
print(f"Time taken for batch_first=True: {time_measure(True)}")
```

On my device (GTX 1050 Ti), PyTorch `1.6.0` and CUDA 11.0 here are the results:

```
Time taken for batch_first=False: 0.3275816479999776
Time taken for batch_first=True: 0.3159054920001836
```

(and it varies either way so nothing conclusive).

### Code readability

`batch_first=True` is simpler when you want to use other PyTorch layers which require `batch` as `0`th dimension (which is the case for almost all `torch.nn` layers like [`torch.nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)).

In this case you would have to `permute` returned tensor anyway if `batch_first=False` was specified.

### Machine translation

It should be better as the `tensor` is contiguous all the time and no copy of data has to be done. It also looks cleaner to slice using `[1:]` instead of `[:,1:]`.

Comment: While the conclusion is correct (these two have no considerable performance difference), the benchmark script is not entirely correct. torch.cuda.synchronize is used to wait for all GPU operations to finish. Therefore, it should be placed before each timer call (e.g., before every time.perf_counter). Otherwise, the GPU operation will continue to run even after the timer stops.